# Eclipse RCP. Java. Create new window

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, desktop

In the main window (which appears after starting the application), I have to make the main menu, it should have a window section, in this section I should select the new window, and after clicking on the new window I should have a new window, and such windows I can create no more than two. (that is, window-> new window)

In the Internet I could not find anything sensible on my question. Prompt how to create new windows (not tabs in a window, namely a new window !!!) in Eclipse RCP or give useful links and even better examples?

And tell me if there is any GUI in Eclipse RCP at all? Or are all the elements added to the window programmatically?

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibility RCP (using org.eclipse.ui.xxx extension points)? Is this just a Dialog / Wizard window you want to open for a short while, or a new window that will stay open?

Comment: This is 3.x compatibility RCP.  About new window, this is new window that will stay open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 3.x compatibility mode RCP use:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().openWorkbenchWindow(perspectiveId, input);
```

`perspectiveId` is the id of the perspective you want the new window to use.

`input` is any `IAdaptable` you want the window to use as its initial input or `null` for no input. A common input is the workspace root: `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()`.